# Pi4 Bullseye - Main Menu problem not showing all items issue

Tags: display

I have a clean install from Raspberry Pi Imager of 32 Bit Bullseye on a P4. I have installed just Shinobi to test for CCTV. I don't recall when this problem appeared but the main menu looks like this :

[image: Main Menu]

I would love to fix this and not do a reinstall

I have tried changing the resolution and it has no impact. I have searched the web and found no hits to fix this.

Comment: what happens if you click the arrows?

Answer (score 0):

it is vnc problem.
edit /boot/config.txt

```
should be commented:
# Enable DRM VC4 V3D driver
#dtoverlay=vc4-kms-v3d
#max_framebuffers=2

should be uncommented:
hdmi_force_hotplug=1
hdmi_group=2
hdmi_mode=16
```

see here:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-7rlLJmNmfA

in my case i use:

```
hdmi_group=2
hdmi_mode=87
hdmi_cvt 1280 800 60 6 0 0 0
hdmi_drive=1
```

Comment: Thanks, perfect